# Object doesn't support this property or method "indexOf"

Tags: asp-classic, jscript

I went through different answers on forums but could not find a solution. So I have an array like this:

```
var valuesArray = ["negative", "underweight", "neutral", "overweight", "positive"];
```

I have two variables:
`var previousRating` and `var currentRating` which dynamically get assigned with one of the values from `valuesArray`.

I am trying to find index of `previousRating` and `currentRating` in `valuesArray` like this:

```
var prevRatingCounter = valuesArray.indexOf(previousRating.toLowerCase());
var curRatingCouter = valuesArray.indexOf(currentRating.toLowerCase());
```

`previousRating` and `curRating` are string values but still I am getting error:

```
Object doesn't support this property or method
```

Can someone please help me figure this out. Thank you.

Comment: if previousRating/curRating are strings, you shouldn't face this issue..
Nevertheless, you have live code?
Put your indexOf code under if(typeof previousRating === "string")

Comment: They are: I did Response.Write and they are indeed strings.

Comment: I'd suggest posting the block of code that you are having issues with instead of describing bits and pieces of it because from what I can see & what you have explained it should work. If you don't want to do that I'd suggest using `console.log()` and the `typeof` operator right before your these lines to make sure no coercion is happening prior.

Comment: I did type of and it is returning as a string.

Comment: Does definition of valuesArray have any problem?

Comment: Are you using IE to check ? [Why doesn't indexOf work on an array IE8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629183/why-doesnt-indexof-work-on-an-array-ie8)

Comment: @SearchAndResQ not relevant, it's classic ASP which is running server side.

Answer (score 3):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28331933/447356), the version of ECMAScript used by server side JScript for writing classic ASP, is only 3.0 - the method `indexOf()` of arrays was introduced only in version 5.0 of ECMAScript as far as I can tell, hence it simply does not exist.

Writing such method isn't that hard, here is a working code sample:

```
<%
function IndexOf(arr, item) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == item) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
%>
```

Then change the code to use it, e.g.

```
var prevRatingCounter = IndexOf(valuesArray, previousRating.toLowerCase());
```

If you need to use it in many different files, you can put the function in a file named e.g. "Common.asp" then include it wherever you need it.

Comment: Cheers, guess I was bit too late. :)

Comment: @Dijkgraaf thanks for fixing the typo, but your other edit is wrong. The backticks are for **inline code**, please don't just add them to full code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have a problem with the inizialization.

This works fine:

```js
     var valuesArray = ["negative", "underweight", "neutral", "overweight", "positive"];

     var previousRating = "underweight";
     var currentRating = "neutral";

     var valuesArray = ["negative", "underweight", "neutral", "overweight", "positive"];

     var prevRatingCounter = valuesArray.indexOf(previousRating.toLowerCase());

     var curRatingCouter = valuesArray.indexOf(currentRating.toLowerCase());

     document.write(prevRatingCounter+" "+curRatingCouter);
```

Comment: I have this code in a '.asp' file. Does that make any difference?