# What is the type of Request.QueryString() and how to check if it's empty?

Tags: asp-classic, jscript, request.querystring

Maybe it's trivial question, but I have no idea what is the type of `Request.QueryString()`. When I check it with typeof - it says it's Object. How to check which object it is and which property of that object is a string in URL?

I'm doing it server side with language specification `<%@ language="javascript"%>`

If I've got URL like that:
http://127.0.0.1/Kamil/Default.asp?name=
then how to check if name is empty? It's not null. I know I can convert `Request.QueryString("name")` to String and check if it's empty string "", but is it proper way?

Comment: Don't confuse JavaScript and JScript, they are different.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf This isn't JavaScript it is Microsoft's flavour of JavaScript used in its server side scripting language Active Server Pages *(known now as Classic ASP)* don't confuse the two this server side version *(denoted by the `<% @language = "JavaScript" %>` is actually called [tag:JScript] confusing I know but don't confuse the two.

Comment: Worth reading the [jscript tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jscript/info) to get a better explanation.

Comment: Also this from the horses mouth - http://stackoverflow.com/a/28331933/692942 *([@Dai](http://stackoverflow.com/users/159145/dai) is an engineer on Microsoft's JavaScript team)*

Comment: Just to directly answer the title, (practically) all variables in Classic ASP are of [type `variant`](http://www.functionx.com/asp/Lesson05.htm), though (somewhat confusingly) there are variant subtypes.

Comment: Worth mentioning -- you can check this yourself in VBScript with the `typename()` function -- i.e. `typename( Request.QueryString )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Request](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524948%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) collection is an object that inherits [IRequestDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524456%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) interface.
In JScript, it's a good practice to use [item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525769(v=vs.90).aspx) to get actual value, not the implicit one due to values of the [QueryString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524784%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) collection (also [Form](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [ServerVariables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525396%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)) are [IStringList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525138%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) in fact. 
You said you know C# so you'll understand the following fictitious QueryString declaration.

```cs
var QueryString = new IRequestDictionary<string, IStringList>();
```

And a few examples how you should check the values in JScript without string conversion.

```
if(Request.QueryString("name").count==0){
    // parameter does not exist
}

if(Request.QueryString("name").item==undefined){
    // parameter does not exist
}

if(Request.QueryString("name").item!=undefined){
    // parameter exists and may be empty
}

if(Request.QueryString("name").item){
    // parameter exists and non-empty
}
```

Comment: IF domain.com?param= AND (Request.QueryString("param").item) THEN Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d'

Comment: @user3751385 It's an expected result :) You shouldn't use this **JScript code** in the VBScript.

Answer (score 2):

The result of `Request.Querystring` (with no name provided) is a string. The result of `Request.Querystring("name")` depends on whether "name" is part of the querystring, and if it is, whether it has a value.

So, given the following querystring:

```
 mypage.asp?A=1&B=
```

If you read them into variables:

```
x = Request.Querystring("A")
y = Request.Querystring("B")
z = Request.Querystring("C")
```

you'll get the following results: x = `"1"` (a string), y = `""` (a blank string), and z = `Empty` (a special value which will be silently converted to a string or a number depending on how you use it, i.e. both `Empty = ""` and `Empty = 0` are in some sense true).

Comment: You're right. `typeof Request.Querystring("name")` shows object, but `typeof new String()` is also object, so it's ok. Javascript doesn't recognize Empty keyword. Variable `z` from your example is not null, not undefined and not empty string. But when converted to String - it's "undefined" (but before conversion it's also object). Can you explain that?

Comment: @alcoholisevil: I'm sorry, I guess I should have been more clear: what I posted is for VBScript, since your asp-classic tag made me assume that that's what you'd be using. Javascript and I aren't on speaking terms, so if you're actually trying to do this client-side (why??), you'll have to ask someone else.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'm doing it on server side with language specification `<%@ language="javascript"%>`. I'm trying to understand ASP before I start learning ASP.NET MVC. I've learned javascript, but I don't want to learn VBScript.

Comment: @alcoholisevil: ah, I see. In that case, I'm afraid my answer is not going to be useful to you. If you want my advice, though, classic ASP and ASP.NET are totally different; knowing the former will not really help you with the latter. If what you want to use is asp.net, just learn asp.net.

Comment: And furthering on the above comment, you will not be able to use javascript as a server side language in ASP.net, so unless you have a pressing need to learn classic ASP go straight to ASP.net (my preference there would be in C#). Also the vast majority of Classic ASP is written in VBScript, so if you're going bother with ASP classic, use VBScript.

Comment: @JonP Classic ASP doesn't have to use VBScript that is just the default out of the box, it can use JScript along with other Active Scripting Languages. There is no requirement to use VBScript at all they are completely interchangeable.

Comment: VBScript is so strange, I don't understand it at all... I know classic ASP is different than ASP.NET but I want to know it a bit before I start learning ASP.NET because I think it's cool and it's good to know what it is. I'm not going to concentrate on it for long time. @Jon P, I know C# and I will use it in ASP.NET.

Comment: @Lankymart, I never said you can't use javascript, just *most* classic ASP is in VBScript

Comment: @JonP That isn't what you said but if it is what you meant that's fine.

Comment: BTW Why in `<%@ language="javascript" %>` it is "javascript"? Why it's not "jscript"? Did Microsoft want to motivate programmers which don't know VBScript to use ASP or the reason is different?

Comment: @alcoholisevil It's both you can specify `<%@ language="jscript" %>` and it will work the same `javascript` is just an alias.